# C, Assigning enum to variable using full name

Tags: c, enums

I'm trying to assign an enum value to an enum variable with its "Full" name in c. Is this possible?:

```
 enum EnumActions{
     SHIFT,
     REDUCE,
     ACCEPT,
     GOTO ,
     ERROR_A 
    };

int main(){
    enum EnumActions __actionType;
    __actionType = EnumActions::SHIFT; //this is giving an error
    __actionType = SHIFT;//this works fine
}
```

any ideas how I can get the first one working?

Comment: You can't. And don't need to. In C, enum value names are in the global space and hence are unique across the entire program. Is there any reason why you think you need/want to do that?

Comment: @AlanAu The reason I want the full name is because it will make things easier to understand in the project.

Comment: "Is there any reason why you think you need/want to do that?"

How about a descriptor that's appropriate and intuitive in multiple sets of enums?  (e.g. Color::Black and Race::Black, instead of the redundant Color::ColorBlack, Race::RaceBlack)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is NO, in C it's not possible.

You could do it with a C++11 `enum class` or with C++ `namespace`'s:

If you want to make it easier to understand you can use a prefix:

```
enum EnumActions{
    ACTION_SHIFT,
    ACTION_REDUCE,
    ACTION_ACCEPT,
    ACTION_GOTO ,
    ACTION_ERROR_A 
};

//...

__actionType = ACTION_SHIFT;
```